# Best Way to Filter Certain Columns in an Array of Arrays in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am trying to filter certain columns in an array of arrays using the index listed in `indexlist`.  The function below is throwing:

> 'The coordinates or dimensions of the range are invalid.'

What's the right approach for this?

```js
function shortenedCol(arrayofarray, indexlist) {
  return arrayofarray.map(function(array) {
    return array.filter(function(el, idx) {
      return this.indexOf(idx) != -1;
    }, this);
  }, indexlist);
}
  var indexlist = [0,2,3];
  var arrayofarray = [['a','b','c','d','e'],['a','b','c','d','e'],['a','b','c','d','e']]
  console.log(shortenedCol(arrayofarray,indexlist));
```

Comment: Please update your question with a **runnable** [mcve] using Stack Snippets (the `[<>]` toolbar button) demonstrating the problem.

Comment: Your [mcve] will need to include *sample input data* that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: I just run the function on my own sampledata, it is working for me.

Comment: do you need the order of the original array? or the order of `indexlist`?

Comment: @NinaScholz, I can accept both.  Your solution runs fine on my data.

Comment: @Stephan, yes it's running fine here. Must be a problem on my data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `indexlist` and map only the values of the specified indices.

```
function shortenedCol(arrayofarray, indexlist) {
    return arrayofarray.map(function (array) {
        return indexlist.map(function (idx) {
            return array[idx];
        });
    });
}
```